# Calling Variable Tags in Product Description

Tags: shopify, liquid

I created a Variable Tag (added it to my theme files) and I'd like to call it from the Product Description. When I call the tag from another liquid file it works... but when I try to call it from the Product Editor it doesn't work.

How can I call a Variable Tag from the Product/WYSIWYG Editor? Do Variable Tags only work in liquid files?

What I added to the theme file: `{% assign favorite_food = 'apples' %}`

What I'm trying to use in the Product Description: `My favorite food is {{ favorite_food }}.`

Comment: That is because the product description does not accept liquid code. Liquid code is compiled prior to the page being loaded and that happens before the product description is grabbed.

Comment: @MMallette ah, that makes sense. Do you know of any alternatives to calling a variable from the product description?

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible but little differently.

Change your product description code like this

`{{ product.description | replace: '[favorite_food]', 'apples' }}`

Now you can use use the shortcode [favorite_food] anywhere in your product description and it will return the value 'apples'.

Just like that you can use product tags or assigned variables with replace string filter.

`{{ product.description | replace: '[price]', product.price }}`

Hope this helps